# Get row item on checkbox Selection in MUI X Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-tsx, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm getting Data from API and displaying it using React MUI X `DataGrid`.
I have enabled check box selection and I want to get the specific cell items of the selected row and save them in a list.

For Example in the image below, if I click on the checkbox for the 1st row I want to get the "current location" added in a list and then if I click on the 2nd row I want current location of 2nd row added in the existing list.

[image]

Below is my current code

```
<DataGrid
   rows={rows}
   columns={columns}
   checkboxSelection     
   onSelectionModelChange={itm => console.log(itm)}
/>
```

But I'm getting output like this

[image]

I'm very new to React and I'm not sure how to get current Location's value for the selected rows and add it to a list.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can only access the row ids inside [`onSelectionModelChange`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#:%7E:text=onSelectionModelChange) callback. If you want to get the whole row objects, use the original `rows` data and filter the others based on the selected ids.

Note: `DataGrid` stores each row ID in string internally so if the ID from your original row data is number you may want to convert it `toString()` before comparing.

```js
rows={rows}
onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
  const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
  const selectedRowData = rows.filter((row) =>
    selectedIDs.has(row.id.toString());
  );
  console.log(selectedRowData);
}}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66424752/get-row-item-on-checkbox-selection-in-react-material-ui-data-grid]

Comment: And how to add selected row item data in a list?

Comment: @Maryam you mean add selected row data programmatically at the start?

Comment: Basically, after displaying the data in a Grid, I have to call an API (post request) on a button click and I have to pass the selected row data in the body of that API call in the form of the list. For Example, if I select 5 rows I want "Current Location" for those 5 rows to be added to a list so that I can pass them in my API call.

Comment: @Maryam I updated the answer and demo for you specific question.

Comment: I'm getting error at this line const selectedRowData = data.rows.filter((row) "Cannot find name 'data'. "

Comment: @Maryam replace the `data.rows` in my code example with your data that you pass to `DataGrid` rows props. From the code in your question it should be `rows` instead of `data.rows`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229374/discussion-between-maryam-and-nearhuscarl).

Comment: Just add a note in my answer for your trouble @Maryam

Comment: `onSelectionModelChange` is not useful that much since on deselection (upper 'check all' checkbox click when some items are checked) it just returns an empty array so it's difficult to determine which rows were deselected.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Do you have any knowledge of a issue with using `selectionModel` to set a group of selected check boxes on initial render?  It would fine on my local but on our prod it errors with a type error of `r = undefined` and `e.current.getRow(...) undefined`

Comment: @Alexey you can store the previous `selectionModel` and find out which ones are deselected if the user hits unselect all.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Sure, but that's an additional logic that should take into consideration cases with server-side pagination when selection should be kept across multiple pages.

Comment: This works 100%!

Comment: how to make row unselected after row selection operation performed successfully?

Comment: i have a model open when the checkbox click but when i uncheck that time also open the model. any solution. 
`<DataGrid
          getRowId={(row)=>row._id}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          checkboxSelection
          onRowSelectionModelChange={(data) => {
              setPostData(data);
              setOpen(true);
          }}
      />`

Comment: As of  "@mui/x-data-grid-premium": "^6.19.2",   ids are integers so remove .toString() in order for this to work.  Also the event is now onRowSelectionModelChange, semicolons removed....

this works.... 
<code>
onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
          const selectedRowData = rows.filter((row) =>
            selectedIDs.has(row.id)
          )
          console.log(selectedRowData);
          console.log(selectedIDs)
<code>

Answer (score 17):

This wasn't working for me until I realised `onSelectionModelChange` is now `onRowSelectionModelChange` in MUI DataGrid (using "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1")

For someone like me who has a hard time deciphering docs before coming to stackoverflow I had to figure this out the hard way i.e. by reading docs.

Comment: yes you are right but there is another issue when you uncheck the checkbox and check again both ways triggering the event. I'm using onRowSelectionModelChange to open a model window.

Comment: this will trigger the event everytime the selection of that row changes (both on select and unselect). My guess is you'll have to use state to make sure it only opens a modal on selecting it and not on un-selecting it.

Answer (score 14):

A simple solution

```
const onRowsSelectionHandler = (ids) => {
    const selectedRowsData = ids.map((id) => rows.find((row) => row.id === id));
    console.log(selectedRowsData);
  };
```

My DataGrid Object

```
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}        
  disableSelectionOnClick
  onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => onRowsSelectionHandler(ids)}
  />
```

Edit:

'onSelectionModelChange' is now 'onRowSelectionModelChange'

Comment: This works 100%!

Comment: 2023 its still works

Answer (score 0):

This is a model of how it could be used in React:

```js
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

<DataGrid
  rows={data}
  columns={columns}
  localeText={ptBR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
  initialState={{
    pagination: {
      paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 5 },
    },
  }}
  pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}
  checkboxSelection
  onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
    const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
    const selectedRows = data.filter((row: any) =>
      selectedIDs.has(row.id)
    );
    setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
  }}
  {...data}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of  "@mui/x-data-grid-premium": "^6.19.2",   ids are integers so remove .toString() in order for this to work.  Also the event is now onRowSelectionModelChange, semicolons removed....

this works....

```
onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
          const selectedRowData = rows.filter((row) =>
            selectedIDs.has(row.id)
          )
          console.log(selectedRowData);
          console.log(selectedIDs)
```